# No click event on <option> in edge using jQuery

Tags: onclick, click, html-select, microsoft-edge

Just figured that there is no click event fired in MS Edge when clicking on a select option.

Here is the code using jQuery 1.9.1:

```js
// data-hide - hide element in data-hide attribute onClick
    $("[data-hide]").bind("click", function(e) {
        $($(this).data("hide")).hide(0);
    });
    // data-show - show element in data-show attribute onClick
    $("[data-show]").bind("click", function(e) {
        $($(this).data("show")).show(0);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="mySelect">
<option value="" data-hide="#d1,#d2,#d3"></option>
<option value="1" data-show="#d1,#d3" data-hide="#d2">1</option>
<option value="2" data-show="#d3" data-hide="#d1,#d2">2</option>
<option value="3" data-show="#d2" data-hide="#d1,#d3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="d1" style="display: none;">
<p>
d1
</p>
</div>
<div id="d2" style="display: none;">
<p>
d2
</p>
</div>
<div id="d3" style="display: none;">
<p>
d3
</p>
</div>
```

Anyone else experiencing this issue?
Any workarounds for edge out there please?

MS Edge is the newest version. Tested on several computers running Win 11 Pro.
Everything works fine in Firefox and Firefox Developer Edition.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the code you provided, I find that the bind event not working with `select:option` element, you can modify the selector to `select`. This should be work, here is my test:

```
// data-hide - hide element in data-hide attribute onClick
$("select").bind("click", function (e) {
   $($("option:selected").data("hide")).hide(0);
});

// data-show - show element in data-show attribute onClick
$("select").bind("click", function (e) {
   $($("option:selected").data("show")).show(0);
});
```

Secondly, you can use select change event to achieve your needs, I think this is suitable，code like this below:

```
$("select").change(function () {
   $($("option:selected").data('hide')).hide();
   $($("option:selected").data('show')).show();
});
```

Comment: This one works just fine.